# Query apex controller Where into a string

Tags: apex, query, controller, where

I am not a developer but I am trying to modify this controller that is available in a component I installed via app exchange.
For what i understood the code is just converting this query into a string to then execute it elsewhere.
I just want to add a WHERE at the end to filter out some values.
For example
WHERE Object1__c.Name contains "Test" ( I am not sure how i can filter the name that contains test ).

How can i do that? Thanks a lot

```
public static List<EventObj> getEvents(String sObjectName, String titleField, String startDateTimeField, String endDateTimeField, String descriptionField, String userField, Boolean filterByUserField){
    String q = 'SELECT Id,' + 
        String.valueOf(titleField) + ',' + 
        String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(descriptionField) + ',' +
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' FROM ' + 
        String.valueOf(sObjectName) + ' WHERE ' + 
        String.valueOf(userField) + ' = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\'' ;
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! You already have a where condition available on `userField`, are you looking to extend the condition to have `userField` and `Name` or should it be one or the other? Note, you reference `Object1__c`, is this the SObject queired in the above String or is it a related object?

Comment: The object 1__c would be related to the event. and for the Name i am referring to the name of the related object, not the event itself.

Comment: Why are you building the query this way? Why not just use an inline query and be done with it?

Comment: it was just written this way by the guy who created the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would be like this with the added condition

```
public static List<EventObj> getEvents(String sObjectName, String titleField, String startDateTimeField, String endDateTimeField, String descriptionField, String userField, Boolean filterByUserField){
String q = 'SELECT Id,' + 
    String.valueOf(titleField) + ',' + 
    String.valueOf(startDateTimeField) + ',' +
    String.valueOf(endDateTimeField) + ',' +
    String.valueOf(descriptionField) + ',' +
    String.valueOf(userField) + ' FROM ' + 
    String.valueOf(sObjectName) + ' WHERE ' + 
    String.valueOf(userField) + ' = \'' + UserInfo.getUserId() + '\'' +' AND ' +Object1__c.Name+' LIKE ' +\'%'+variable where your 'test' is stored+'%\';
```

Comment: I am getting so many errors after the addition, i guess i need to declare the variable where the string test is stored? can't i just hard code it there?

Comment: you could hard code it as follows: +' AND ' +Object1__c.Name+' LIKE ' +\'%Test%\';   do let me know if you face any more problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ahamed

Comment: @Brian23Gt please mark the answer as best answer if it helps you.